# Crear un fichero con un vector y ordenarlo

Tags: c, archivo

Quiero crear un fichero en el cual se cree el vector y ordenarlo.

Tengo escrito hasta aqui:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int vector[10] ={'9','5','3','1','10','2','6','4','8','7'};    
int largo = 10;    
FILE *fichero;

fichero = fopen("C:/temp/arreglo.txt","w+");  
fwrite(vector, sizeof(int), sizeof(vector), fichero );

for(int i=0; i<10; i++){    
    printf("%i",vector[i]);    
    }

fclose(fichero);    
return 0;    
}
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: El post no formula una pregunta técnica o de lógica. Plantea un trabajo que tiene que hacer, con unos requisitos (amplios) y la pregunta es "¿Alguien me puede ayudar?". Formule cual es su duda concreta informando qué es lo que aún no hace el programa que está publicando, o que error le arroja, o que comportamiento no esperado realiza el código que está publicando.

Comment: Buenas, el frite está mal formulado, seria `fwrite(vector, sizeof(int), 10, fichero);`.

Luego, varias cosas que he visto: al crear el puntero te recomiendo que lo inicializes a NULL, esto es algo que algunos compiladores hacen, pero no todos (`FILE *fichero = NULL;`). Al abrirlo hay que comprobar si el fichero no es NULL (así te aseguras de que se ha abierto correctamente). Constantes como el '10' de tu array suelen ponerse bajo un `#define`, arriba del todo (algo estilo `#define SIZE 10` y luego `int vector[SIZE] = ...`). Una duda de tu pregunta, ¿el vector es un array de 10 ints?

Comment: si es un arrays de 10 enteros

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Sigo sin entender que le pasa a ese código, ¿cuál es el problema? ¿Qué error produce? ¿Qué resultado esperas en tiempo de ejecución? Falta muchos detalles en esta pregunta. Te invito a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)..